# Completeness of Normed spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following proposition

If $(X,||\cdot||)$ and $(X,||\cdot||')$ are homeomorphic, then $(X,||\cdot||)$ is complete if and only if $(X,||\cdot||')$ is complete.

So, I only know the definition of homeomorphic, and can't figure out how only with that I can prove that proposition. Can someone help me to prove this please?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

As a sketch$\ldots$

Well if you've a homeomorphism $f$, then if $\{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is cauchy wrt $\|\cdot \|$, and converges to $x \in X$, then $\|x_n-x\|<\delta$ for $n$ sufficiently large, and $\|x_n-x_m\|<\delta$, for $n,m$ sufficiently large. Since $f$ is continuous we can make $\|f(x_n)-f(x_m)\|'<\epsilon$ for $\|x_n-x_m\|<\delta$, so $\{f(x_n)\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is cauchy. Now since $f$ is continuous at $x$ we also know that $\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|'<\epsilon$ for $\|x_n-x_m\|<\delta$. So $f(x_n)$ will converge to $f(x)$. Then to prove the other way, you do the same thing, except with $f^{-1}$, which is continuous since $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Let me think a little bit in this, If I get stuck can I tell you?

Comment: yeah of course you can! And I can tighten up the proof in a while if you want, make it less of a sketch

Comment: Yes I apprwciate that please :)

Comment: Is this a corollary of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402775/prove-the-following-theorem-involving-homeomorphic-metric-spaces

Comment: @user162343 yes the norm on a vector space gives a metric where $d(x,y)=\| x-y\|$

Comment: Then Can Iedit that question so I can post the answer for it (it is my question, I've post it yesterday) then I ask you a verification please :)

Comment: I am back, the thing is that I have told the teacher about this, and he told me that it is not a corollary :(, then what can be done here?

Comment: @user162343 I'm not sure what you meant by yesterday's comment. With regards to the corollary thing, if you prove the exact statement about completeness of metric spaces, then normed spaced give rise to a metric, and the proof for metric spaces hold, but I suppose you don't really need to refer to any specific as the proof should stand alone as is. If you give me a few minutes I'll give you a more rigorous proof of this statement. We are talking about vector spaces though?

Comment: Well maybe, maybe not, they are only normed spaces, and yes please I appreciate that you helpme with that please :).

Answer (score 1):

Take a Cauchy sequence in $(X,||\cdot||)$ and show that is also a Cauchy sequence in $(X,||\cdot||')$.

This proves the assertion since convergence is a topological property which is preserved by homeomorphisms.

Comment: Let me think a little bit in this, If I get stuck can I tell you?

Comment: Is this a corollary of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402775/prove-the-following-theorem-involving-homeomorphic-metric-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Since $(X, ||\cdot || ) $ and $ (X, ||\cdot ||' )$ are homeomorphic the topologies generated by these norms are identical. Hence the identity map $\mbox{Id} :(X, ||\cdot || ) \to (X, ||\cdot ||' )$ is continiuous so the norms are equivalent. And from the equivalence of the norms it easily follows your assertion.

Comment: Let me think a little bit in this, If I get stuck can I tell you?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701665/does-homeomorphism-imply-an-equivalent-norm

Comment: How do you prove that the norms are equivalent?

Comment: Is this a corollary of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402775/prove-the-following-theorem-involving-homeomorphic-metric-spaces

Comment: How do you prove that the norms are equivalent?